# A priority tree is a binary tree where, whenever v is a child of u, priority(u) ≥ priority(v)

Tags: algorithm, math, heap, time-complexity, priority-queue

A priority tree is a binary tree where, whenever v is a child of u, `priority(u) ≥ priority(v)`. That
is, it is a heap which is not necessarily a complete tree.

(a) Let H1 and H2 be two heaps represented as trees. Describe an efficient way to produce a priority
tree that contains all the elements of H1 and H2. The operation should take time   `O(log(|H1| + |H2|))`, where `|H|` means the number of elements in heap H.

I've tried a few different methods but can't get the right time complexity. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: how is the data stored?

Comment: its stored in an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: your definition of "priority tree" is a simple min-heap. So basically your problem is just to merge the two heaps into one.

A simple approach to this would be the following: take the heap with the smaller root and merge the other heap into it. Start from the root of the heap into which is inserted and follow an arbitrary path, until the node has a value that is larger than the root of the heap to insert. Replace that node with the heap to insert. Now you've got a new heap to insert (the one you just removed from the heap). Just proceed with the above starting from the node you just inserted until the heap to insert is finally empty.

```
//if at least one heap is empty, the job is already done
if H1.isEmpty()
    return H2
if H2.isEmpty()
    return H1

//select heap to insert into and heap to be inserted
node insInto, toIns, prntInsInto
if H1.getRoot() > H2.getRoot()
    insInto = H2.getRoot()
    toIns = H1.getRout()
else
    insInto = H1.getRoot()
    toIns = H2.getRoot()

heap result = insInto
//merge
while toIns != null
    if insInto == null
       //we've run to the lower end of the heap to insert into
       //just append the heap to insert and youre done
       prntInsInto.setLeftChild(toIns)
       return result

    if insInto > toIns
       //replace node in heap into which is insert with the root of the heap to insert
       prntInsInto.replace(insInto , toIns)

       //removed subtree becomes new heap to insert
       //and inserted subtree becomes new heap into which is inserted
       node tmp = toIns
       toIns = insInto
       insInto = tmp

   //I selected the left child for the search, this is
   //completely random, you could even replace it with the
   //larger of the two children for better efficiency 
   prntInsInto = insInto
   insInto = insInto.leftChild()

return result
```

This algorithm uses the fact, that min-heaps can be defined recursively as `H = (N , L , R)`, where `N` is the root of the heap and `L` and `R` are respectively the left and right children, which are heaps aswell.

This algo runs with worst-cast `O(log |H1| + log |H2|)`. Faster isn't possible.

EDIT:
Just noticed the comment saying the heaps are stored as arrays. In this case a logarithmic runtime is simply impossible, since all elements will have to be traversed in order to achieve that runtime. Thus `O(|H1| + |H2|)` will be the best you can do in that case, since the above algo relies on the fact that an already existing data-structure can be manipulated in `O(1)`, which is not given for arrays.

Comment: @JaredGoguen take a closer look. That's not java. Code-blocks are marked by indention, no semicolons... In fact that's just my preferred style of writing pseudocode.